# Adding a new computed variable back to main dataset in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to compute a variable (say last_week) and add it back to my main dataset (say new_j). I managed to join it to new_j. However, if I want to use that variable (last_week) now for further calculations, it does not recognise it. Here's my code:

```
SELECT [Weekkey] AS weekkey
  ,[article / colour] as prod_id
  ,[Current MP Department No/Desc] as prod_dept
  ,[Total Stock] as total_stock
INTO #new_j
FROM [J_20160831] --(that’s the db in server and I created a temp db #new_j)

SELECT prod_id, max(weekkey) as last_week
into #lastweeksales
FROM #new_j
group by prod_id

select *
from #new_j
left join #lastweeksales
       on #lastweeksales.prod_id = #new_j.prod_id
```

So, I joined both successfully and if I run this code, I see column last_week. Now what I want to do is this:

```
select *
,case
       when last_week = max(weekkey) then total_stock
       else 0
end as last_stock_position
from #new_j
```

But it says last_week is not found in new_j. I also tried #lastweeksales.last_week instead of just last_week in the last bit of code, but it didn't either. What's the best way out here? Moreover, is there a better way to do it instead?. The output I am looking to have at the end is a table with these variables: WeekKey, prod_dept, prod_id, total_stock, last_week, last_stock_position

Thanks for the help!!! Much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This normal behaviour of joins..

by selecting this

```
select * from #new_j left join #lastweeksales
       on #lastweeksales.prod_id = #new_j.prod_id'
```

all the columns of newj and lastweekales will be displayed in same order (first new_j columns and then lastweeksales columns ).So 'last_week' is the last column of lastweeksales.

Secondly,

```
select *,
       case when last_week = max(weekkey) then total_stock
            else 0
       end as last_stock_position
from #new_j
```

in above query,your are selecting 'last_week' column which belongs to the table #lastweeksales.

Be careful while selecting the columns.

I guess your expecting,

```
 select a.WeekKey, a.prod_dept, a.prod_id, a.total_stock, b.last_week, 
 case
   when b.last_week = max(a.weekkey) then total_stock
   else 0
end as last_stock_position
from #new_j as a
 left join #lastweeksales as b
 on b.prod_id = a.prod_id
 group by a.weekkey,a.prod_dept,a.prod_id,a.total_stock,b.last_week
```

Comment: Thanks KK, thats exactly my question. How do I use last_week column which is in #lastweeksales AND total_stock column from #new_j to compute a new variable. Although joining both joins the dataset but still doesn't store as a new dataset - so how can I store that combined dataset as a new one?

Comment: i have updated the answer,i guess is this helps.Mark this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks KK! That's on the lines of what I was looking for, however, got this error - Column '#new_j.weekkey' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. :/

Comment: Now i have updated the answer. Sorry i missed the group by columns